# .NET Reflector for Mono

Tags: mono, reflector

Is there an equivalent of .NET Reflector for Mono? Quick googling did not find anything... Or can I run Reflector on Mono (say, in Mac OS X)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I was looking for a Mono decompiler, I found this page and tested the answers :

- Mono.Cecil works great but it's a library and I was looking for a GUI
- ILSpy doesn't run under Mono (Linux) since it uses WPF. Same for .NET CodeReflect, JustDecompile and dotPeek.
- Perhaps Reflector works, but I don't really want to pay to know

Finally I found it was possible to decompile assemblies directly in [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

Comment: How did you achieve decompiling assemblies directly in MonoDevelop?  I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: @Micah Delane Bolen, this surely deserves its own question, but I will be generous this time :)  Add your dll file as a reference to your project. Then double-click on the reference and TADAM the awesome MonoDevelop will show you the decompiled code.

Comment: I see the interface in MonoDevelop but NOT the decompiled code.

Comment: @user430788 You have to select the C# language at the top right corner in the assembly navigator.

Comment: Even easier, just "File -> Open" the DLL file in a new MonoDevelop instance and do what @antoyo said. No need to create a project / add as reference

Answer (score 10):

Reflector works fine on Mono (at in older versions), provided you turn off the "Show PDB symbols" option.

Miguel de Icaza [blogged about this](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2007/02/22/reflector-on-mono-1-2-3.aspx) at one point.

Comment: to my surprise, you're right, it does work on Mac OS X!!! Just do "mono reflector.exe" in terminal!!!

Comment: How do you get reflector.exe without Windows? Currently, their download is an installer which doesn't run under mono.

Comment: @Eliot Copy it across - old versions were zip deployments...

Comment: @Reed You're assuming I have a copy of Windows. ;)
But yes, I'll try that when I have a chance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new project called ILSPY that is trying to build an open source version of reflector: http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx

Comment: ILSPY works quite well, I have added it to the O2 Platform and am now using it every day (instead of reflector)

Comment: I tried IlSpy, but it tells me the same as Reflector ** (ILSpy.exe:10897): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from ****/ilSpy/ILSpy.exe could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   PresentationFramework    (assemblyref_index=5)
     Version:    4.0.0.0
     Public Key: 31bf3856ad364e35
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (****/ilSpy/).

Comment: ILSpy is WPF based, and it cannot run on Mono yet.

Comment: You can use it as a cli application, see e.g. https://github.com/andreif/ILSpyMono

Answer (score 2):

Have any one tried [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) ?

With Cecil, you can load existing managed assemblies, browse all the contained types, modify them on the fly and save back to the disk the modified assembly; potentially might even be more powerful than Reflector!

I am about to review it.

Answer (score 2):

[Mono Cecil.](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)
Red-Gate Reflector is totaly based on it.
[Se this RedGate forum post for more information](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=12756).

Answer (score 1):

reflector 6.0 dose not support Mono,only 5.1.7supports mono.

mono  reflector.exe /compat

:)