# MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio freezes after launch on OS X

Tags: macos, monodevelop, freeze

I've installed MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio 4.0.9 on OS X 10.8 for browsing assemblies as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228086/753737).

It starts correctly but after showing the main window it freezes (spinning beach ball, Activity Monitor says that "Application is not responding").

I've correctly installed Mono 3.1.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the process property in Activity Monitor, I noticed that Xamarin Studio loaded some libraries from Mono 3.1.2 and others from Mono 2.10.11 (which I have installed before). I've uninstalled Mono using the script found at the end of the [Mono OS X page](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX#Uninstalling_Mono_on_Mac_OS_X) and I reinstalled version 3.1.2: then I launched Xamarin Studio, I've created a project, added a reference to NUnitLite and I've been able to inspect it.

It seems Xamarin Studio does not like different versions of Mono installed side by side: I understand that this may be related to the fact that as of 2013-07-20 Xamarin products are still being updated to Mono 3.0 (see for example [this thread in the Mono mailing list](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Should-3-0-3-be-Listed-as-Stable-td4658104.html) and [this page](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview) and [this blog post](http://blog.xamarin.com/brave-new-async-mobile-world/) on async support for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS)

**Update** Before installing Mono 3.1.2, I've researched if I needed to uninstall previous versions of Mono. I found this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298859/correct-way-to-install-mono-framework-in-os-x) that suggested that there were no problem on having multiple versions side-by-side, so I installed Mono 3.1.2 leaving the old version installed and I've checked from the command line that the right version of `mcs` was invoked.